# How to Change Light and Dark Theme Colors for Material-UI AppBar?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, theming

I'm not very deep into React yet...

The AppBar is styled like a button which i don't like.

So I want to change it's colors but also have it working switching light and dark scheme.

[Edit]
I want to define own colors for AppBar (without changing present colors) und add them to light/dark theme respectively so it's changing automatically to light/dark when i switch themes.
[/Edit]

Changing colors with ThemeProvider is already not working:

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
    palette: {
        // type: 'dark'
    },
    overrides: {
        MuiTypography: {
            h1: {
                fontSize: 24,
                fontWeight: "normal"
            },
            h2: {
                fontSize: 22,
                fontWeight: "normal"
            },
        },
        MuiAppBar: {
            background: 'white',
            borderBottom: "1px solid lightGray",
        }
    },
```

MuiTypography works, though.
(As I see here https://material-ui.com/customization/default-theme/ there's no AppBar only Typography.)

How can I tell AppBar to use other colors than primary/secondary while staying synced with the built-in light-dark-theme mechanic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ciao, if you want to switch theme (from dark theme to light theme for example) you could use `primary` and `secondary` colors (previously defined in `theme` object).

So lets take [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-prominent-appbar-forked-bqb77?file=/demo.js) codesandbox example I made:

1. I defined 2 colors in theme:

   ```
   const Theme = {
     palette: {
       primary: {
         main: "#000000"
       },
       secondary: {
         main: "#FFFFFF"
       }
     }
   };
   ```

In this case, `primary` is our dark theme and `secondary` is the light theme.

2. I created MUI theme:

   ```
   const theme = createMuiTheme(Theme);
   ```
3. I wrapped the `AppBar` component into a `ThemeProvider` with the `theme` created:

   ```
   <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
     <AppBar position="static" color={themeSelected}>
     ....
     </AppBar>
   </ThemeProvider>
   ```

As you can see on `AppBar` component, I putted a state variable in `color` props (`themeSelected`).

Well now I created just a simple `IconButton` with an `SwapHoriz` icon [image], and on click I change my state variable `themeSelected`:

```
...

const [themeSelected, setThemeSelected] = useState("primary"); // init as primary color

...

const changeTheme = () => {  // function to set state
   if (themeSelected === "primary") setThemeSelected("secondary");
   else setThemeSelected("primary");
};

...

<IconButton   //icon button with onClick handler
   className={classes.menuButton}
   color="inherit"
   aria-label="open drawer"
   onClick={() => {
      changeTheme();
   }}
>
   <SwapHoriz />
</IconButton>
```

Thats it. Now if you click `SwapHoriz` you can change your color theme:

**Primary color theme**

[image]

**Secondary color theme**

[image]

**EDIT**

After you explanation, I understood that you want distinct colors for AppBar and, when you change theme, AppBar should take that colors.

In this case the only way I know is to override the `classes` of AppBar in this way:

```
<AppBar
   position="static"
   color={themeSelected}
   classes={{
      colorPrimary: classes.appbarpalette,
      colorSecondary: classes.appbarpalette
   }}
>
```

Then in your `makeStyles`:

```
...
appbarpalette: {
    "&.MuiAppBar-colorPrimary": {
      backgroundColor: purple[600] // instead of #000000 for primary now you have purple
    },
    "&.MuiAppBar-colorSecondary": {
      backgroundColor: green[600] // instead of #FFFFFF for secondary now you have green
    }
  }
```

I updated my codesandbox example.

Comment: I don't completely get it: I want to define own colors for AppBar und add it to light/dark theme respectively so it's changing automatically when i switch themes.

Comment: Oh I got it. AppBar should have his own color. Ok, let me modify my answer.

Comment: @sntrcode I updated my answer. I hope o have done what you requested. Let me know if I didn't get the point :)

Comment: Looks good! React is really a hard nut to crack and I cannot really tell atm how well this corresponds to this reference [link](https://material-ui.com/customization/palette/) where I just have to write pallette:{type: 'dark'}. I must say that React is quite concise documented for beginners, too. I don't know too if I should mark your answer solved as I hope to get some more answers tomorrow. I'd like to already give you credit and really appreciate your help!

Comment: No problem. This is only my way to use Material UI (and I'm not the maximum expert ;) ). Lets wait for other answers. Maybe there is someone that could teach us something more :).